# Rails 3 boolean value not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean

I have a Rails 3.2 application. I am trying to update a boolean field in my form, but it's not getting updated.

my form is as follows :

```
.pocketNSleeve
   %span Want Half Sleeves:
   = f.check_box :half_sleeve, :id => "halfSleeve"
   %span Want Pocket
   = f.check_box :pocket, :id => "wantPocket"
```

I am assigning values to these check boxes by javascript.

my create action is as follows :

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(params[:line_item])   
  @product = @line_item.product
  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.js
    else
      @line_item_id = @line_item.check_bag
      @product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

When I am debugging it with 'pry' gem I get the required parameters properly in my params.

after @line_item.save I tried manual update also using .update method as follows :

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(params[:line_item])   
  @product = @line_item.product
  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      @line_item.update_column('pocket', params[:line_item][:pocket])
      @line_item.update_column('half_sleeve', params[:line_item][:half_sleeve])
      format.js
    else
      @line_item_id = @line_item.check_bag
      @product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

below are the parameters :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3FGs6NIkDMjaqerG9RNyKZTWNRq09Avmv3TW2RCrzac=",
 "line_item"=>
  {"product_size_id"=>"3",
   "quantity"=>"01",
   "half_sleeve"=>"true",
   "pocket"=>"false",   
   "cart_id"=>"103811",
   "product_id"=>"50",
   "product_code"=>"19408ARD",
   "ordered_price"=>"1600.0"}, 
 "commit"=>"ADD TO CART",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"line_items"}
```

There are some callbacks in my model, but those are not doing any harmful waork.

Comment: You don't need to it manually rails does it automatically

Comment: It's not doing it in my case, so I tried manually, still its not working!

Comment: Without the model and model relations, it is hard to say what exactly is happening here

Comment: what are the params you are getting?, are you sure you are getting checkbox values inside `params[:line_item]` please check once.

Comment: I have edited the question to list the parameters which I am getting in my controller action

Comment: 'pocket' and 'half_sleeve' are the checkbox params

Comment: try saving using 0 and 1 instead of 'true' or 'false' and check